# onbeforeunload & Master Pages - Should it work?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Should the onbeforeunload event fire on a child page within asp.net?
The code runs fine in a non-master/content asp.net page, but not in a master/content scenario.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Classic ASP.NET'...

Comment: It works in a live environment - just not when run within Visual Studio!